# Save doesn't get enabled on SWT EditorPart when cell is modified in TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp, tableviewer

I'm using a `TableViewer` in my class which extends `EditorPart`, `TableViewer` has one
editable column which has `ComboBoxCellEditor`. When I modify the column to select a value from `ComboBoxCellEditor`, the save button doesn't get enabled until a tab key is pressed, or when the focus is moved to a different item. Is there any way that I can get the save to be enabled when I modify the value of `ComboBoxCellEditor`. I'm extending `EditingSupport` class to make the column editable. The overridden medthods from this class are not called until the focus is shifted away from this column. Is there any way that I can get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how `ComboBoxCellEditor` is designed to work. The internal method `applyEditorValueAndDeactivate` is only called on Tab, Enter, and focus lost.

None of this behavior looks easy to modify other than by writing your own version of the class (which is not large).

Comment: any suggestions on how to write our own version?

Comment: Reading the source of ComboBoxCellEditor which has quite a lot of comments.

Comment: I got it to work according to my own use, thanks for your insight